# ¿como incluir la validacion de una Regex en una promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Tengo la siguiente funcion para cuando se hace click en el boton "guardar":

```
async confirm () {
      helperModal.showWindowContentLoading()
      let response = await ApiService.post('/config/updateExtraConfiguration', {
        google_tag_manager_code: this.googleTagManagerCode
      });

      if (response.success) {
        this.messageManager.showSuccessMessage(this.translateText('Se han guardado correctamente los cambios.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      } else {
        this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText('No se han podido guardar los cambios. Intenta nuevamente.'))
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      }
    },
```

y tengo que tambien chequear que el codigo ingresado en el input sea valido.

para eso tuve en otro archivo esta funcion:

```
this.validate = function() {
        var GTMCodeRegex = /^(GTM-[A-Z0-9]+)$/i,
            GTMCode = $.trim($(self.ELEMENTS.META_INPUT).val()),
            validEmpty = options['validEmpty'] || false;

        if ((GTMCode != '' && !GTMCodeRegex.test(GTMCode)) || (GTMCode == '' && !validEmpty)) {
            return { valid : false, message : i18nHelper.getText('El código de seguimiento de google no es válido') };
        }
        return { valid : true };
    };
```

como puedo hacer para que la validación de lo ingresado sea chequeado cuando se hace click en el boton guardar? 
o sino al ingresar el codigo en el input puede ser otra opcion.

Tambien podria ser incluido en el @change de mi input en vue

input:

```
 <b-input
          type="text"
          id="googleTagManagerInput"
          :value="googleTagManagerCode"
          :maxlength="12"
          placeholder="GTM-XXXXXX"
          @change="updatetagmanagercode"
        />
```

El method actual del updatetagmanagercode:

```
updatetagmanagercode (value) {
      this.googleTagManagerCode = value
```

Comment: y no puedes hacer algo como `async confirm () { if validate(){ ..}`?

Comment: Si @JackNavaRow pero no se como armar la promise correctamente